Problems sending data with IdTCPServer and TIdThreadSafeObjectList using TMemoryStream
I'm missing something trying to implement sending TMemoryStream data because when I try to send them to clients in TMyContext.SendQueue() the streams are empty.
Here is my simplified code:
TMyContext = class(TIdServerContext)
  private
    Context_ID: string;
    Queue: TIdThreadSafeObjectList;
    QueuePending: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AddToQueue(const ms: TMemoryStream);
    procedure SendQueue;
  end;
...
...

constructor TMyContext.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  Queue := TIdThreadSafeObjectList.Create;
end;

destructor TMyContext.Destroy;
begin
  Queue.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyContext.AddToQueue(const ms: TMemoryStream);
var
  List: TList;
begin
  List := Queue.LockList;
  try
    list.Add(ms);
    QueuePending := True;
  finally
    Queue.UnlockList;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyContext.SendQueue;
var
  list: TList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if not QueuePending then
    Exit;

  list := Queue.LockList;
  try
    if list.Count = 0 then
    begin
      QueuePending := False;
      Exit;
    end;

    for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      Connection.IOHandler.Write( TMemoryStream(List[i]), 0, True); // here List[i] size is 0
      // does the TMemoryStream object in OnExecute() still exist?

    list.Clear;
    QueuePending := False;
  finally
    Queue.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
...
...
procedure TServer.IdTCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  LContext: TMyContext;
  ms: TMemorySTream;
begin
  LContext := TMyContext(AContext);

  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    ...
    ...
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msgFromClient, size);
    msgFromClient.Position:= 0;
    ...

    // get some values from stream
    ...
    LContext.Context_ID  := Get_ID(ms);

  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TServer.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  LContext,Ctx_Peer2: TMyContext;
  List: TList;
  I: integer;
begin
  LContext := TMyContext(AContext);

  //send pending messages from the server
  LContext.SendQueue;


  //check for a message received from the client
  if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(100);
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;

  size:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongInt;
  try
    try
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msgStream, size);
    except
      Exit;
    end;

    // do some stuuf with ms stream
    ...
    ...

    // put new data into ms and send to the calling context queue
    ms.clear:= 0;
    ...
    ...
    ms.position := 0;
    LContext.AddToQueue(ms);

    // put new data into ms and send to another peer
    // do I have to use a different TMemoryStream variable than ms here?
    ms.clear:= 0;
    ...
    ...
    ms.position := 0;
    List := IdTCPServer.Contexts.LockList;
    try

      for I := 0 to List.Count-1 do
      begin
        if (TMyContext(List[I].Context_ID = context_id_i_want_to_send) then
        begin
          Ctx_Peer2 := TMyContext(List[I]);
          Break;
        end;
      end;
      Ctx_Peer2.AddToQueue(ms);
    finally
      IdTCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
    end;

  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TServer.IdTCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Ctx: TMyContext;
begin
  Ctx := TMyContext(AContext);
  Ctx.Context_ID = '';
  Ctx.Queue.Clear;
end;

Still in SendQueue(), I don't think each stream is sent to the right client because it seems to me that this connection is missing; do I have to scroll through all available contexts?

Your code exhibits undefined behavior, for several different reasons:

You are freeing the TMemoryStream object in the same thread that queues it, so it may be invalid when another thread tries to send it. Once the object has been added to a queue, do not free it until you remove it from that queue. TIdThreadSafeObjectList has an OwnsObjects property that you can set to True to take ownership and free the objects for you.

You are adding the same TMemoryStream object to multiple queues. After you add it to a queue, you are clearing its data. In between each add, any client you previously queued it to may try to send it. That could easily account for the 0 sizes you are seeing. Each queued message must be a distinct object, DO NOT reuse objects that have been queued.

In your loop that iterates the Contexts list looking for a client to send to, if that client is not found then your Ctx_Peer2 variable will not be pointing at a valid object when you call AddToQueue() on it. You need to either initialize Ctx_Peer2 to nil and then check it for nil after the loop exits, or else simply move the call to AddToQueue() to inside the loop where a match is found.



Despite the errors, I am happy to have been on the right path and with the corrections you suggested it now works perfectly. Great as usual Remy, thank you very much
